# How to use ninject.extensions.wf in WCF xamlx service for WF 4.0 hosted by AppFabric?

Tags: c#, wcf, ninject, workflow-foundation, appfabric

I am developing a WCF service to host windows workflow under AppFabric and want to use IoC. I found a nice extension for Ninject (ninject.extensions.wf). Unfortunately, I can't find how to configure WCF service configuration file to have  it working. I searched for an complete example with the extension but found nothing. On official wiki page (and related posts from owners), the partial example is not clear for me and I am confused what settings I have to have in my project. It will be great help if somebody can share their experience posting an example with WCF service which uses the extension or at least WCF web.config settings.